# Stream video file which is still being downloaded NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to stream a *mp4 video* file while it is still downloading in the back-end. Just like some *torrent* clients can, torrent is still downloading, but you can already start watching the video.

Currently I have it somewhat working using `ranges` and `fs.createReadStream`

```
var stat = fs.statSync('/path/to/file.mp4'); // this file gets downloaded when requested
var total = stat.size;

console.log(prettyBytes(total));

if (request.headers.range) {
    var range = request.headers.range;
    var parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
    var partialstart = parts[0];
    var partialend = parts[1];

    var start = parseInt(partialstart, 10);
    var end = partialend ? parseInt(partialend, 10) : total-1;
    var chunksize = (end-start)+1;

    var file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start: start, end: end});
    
    resource.writeHead(206, { 'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + total, 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Length': chunksize, 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' });
    file.pipe(resource);
} 
else {
    resource.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Length': total, 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' });
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(resource);
}
```

This is currently working, the video can be played in the browser. However, as soon as I start seeking in the *HTML5 video player*, the player jumps back to `00:00` and starts over. The video also stops after a few minutes, because that part was downloaded when the video started.

When I reload the browser, the `mp4` file has been downloaded a bit more and now I can seek a bit further, but eventually it fails again and starts at `00:00`, even if the video is fully downloaded.

I stumbled upon this package [node-growing-file](https://github.com/felixge/node-growing-file), which appears to be what I am looking for. But this package seems to be abandoned by its owner. Is there a alternative?

Is this even possible using `NodeJS`?

Comment: Just to be clear, in reality, you're proxying this file from some other server?  If so, why write it to disk?  And if not, what why not use `express.static()`?

Comment: @brad The files are downloaded by torrents using nodejs. We cannot use `express.static()` because the files are removed again after *14 days* and the files are too big for that `4gb+`.

Comment: Why not stream the data as you receive it?  You want to cache it to local disk as well?

Comment: @brad yes, it is cached for 14 days to local disk. How do you mean "stream as you receive it?"

Comment: Client requests bytes zero through say 1MB... you download the first couple chunks of the torrent, and as you get the data in, you flush those buffers directly to the client.  And in your case, to disk as well... although the parts on disk don't have to be written in-order of course.  You just need to track what you're getting so you know when you can send data to the client.

Comment: If it were me, I wouldn't bother reinventing all this... we already have WebTorrent, which fits your use case.  https://webtorrent.io/

Comment: @brad, we use webtorrent.io to download the files, however .. streaming the files in the browser doesn't work that well using webtorrent.io.

Comment: Alright, well, if you're not happy with MediaSource and you still want to go the HTTP route, you simply need to *not* rely on the on-disk information.  The browser client can't know or care that your local file is incomplete yet.  So, when you give it the total size, that needs to come from the torrent information.  Otherwise, you're essentially just representing a corrupt file.

Comment: Complicating things is that you're using MP4, which if not set up for streaming will requiring seeking to the end of the file before playback can begin.  (This is common.)  That's why you need to add some logic to your torrent fetching, to get the chunks faster that the browser is requesting.

Comment: @brad the total size is already fetched from the torrent information. However, when using the actual size of the file, the video cannot play, because its trying to playback a larger file than it currently has. The file size is recalculated each time the server requests new bytes.

Comment: Right, that's my point.  Right now you're using `fs.statSync()` to get the file size to send to the client, but you can't do that and expect it to work.  The client needs to know how big the file is, whether you've finished downloading it or not.  `Content-Length` and `Content-Range` need to contain the correct total sizes.  And, I'm saying that the next problem you're going to run into after that is fixed is that the client will likely be requesting bytes from the end of the file, which you need to supply as soon as you have them.

Comment: @brad I am going to try to change that part `var total = stat.size`. I come back to you.

Comment: @brad, thanks for the responses. I figured it out, I had to pass the actual video size to `var total = stat.size`. Not the current size of it while it was being downloaded.